# unable to use groupby function in pandas for dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 100+ rows, where i need to extract values w.r.t 'High' column using groupby. But I am unable to do it.

My dataframe sample is:

```
           Date     Open     High  ...    Volume              
           Date     Open     High  ...    Volume 
0    24-04-2020  1840.10  1851.60  ...     93384      
1    23-04-2020  1786.00  1891.70  ...    453645     
2    22-04-2020  1746.00  1789.10  ...    103696      
3    21-04-2020  1775.00  1794.00  ...    149222
```

I have stored the dataframe in a variable `data_frame` and when I try using `data_frame.groupby('High')`, I am getting the following error message:

> "ValueError: Grouper for 'High' not 1-dimensional".

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Looks like the dataframe header is repeated twice which makes it multi-dimensional. Check the first 2 rows with column names. Should there be just one?

Comment: @MayankPorwal No,header is of 2 rows.

Comment: Then it is the problem if the header is on 2 rows, I guess it is multiindex, so try `data_frame.groupby(('High', 'High'))`, but I would rather fix the columns if possible

Comment: @Ben.T Thanks for the suggestion. It worked for me. how can i print only the max value in this column with date column after groupby?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want here. Can you add in your question the expected output in the case your data was only the few rows you provided?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the header, the header has multi-index and so specifying only one column name gives you error. 
You can set the column headers using the `df.columns`. If you want to access the `High` column, then simple use `loc` or `data_frame['High']

```
data_frame.columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Volume'] #add more
```

If you want to get the max value of the `High` column based on the date, then you have to use groupby on `Date` and project the `High` column.

```
data_frame.groupby(['Date'])['High'].max()
```